# How can I use the Feed Dialog to post on a Facebook Fan Page wall not liked by the user?

Tags: facebook

**UPDATE: Facebook's API has changed a lot since this question was posted. This question is not relevant anymore.**

I'm making an iOS application for an online radio and I want the users to be able to post messages on the radio's Facebook Fan Page which, by the way, has all the permissions set to allow everyone to post on it's wall.

I know that users can post on the fan page no matter if they "liked" or not the fan page if they are on the fan page. However, at least with the Facebook's iOS and Javascript SDKs, the feed dialog would display the following error if the user hasn't liked the page:

> An invalid target was specified: 219909461711. The target must be a
>   page, event or user that the actor can post on the wall of.

"219909461711" would be the ID number of the target profile, which is the Radio's Facebook Fan Page. If you use the Fan Page's path name, the SDK changes it for the Fan Page's profile ID number.

Am I doing something wrong? Why is it that the dialog displays this error if the user is being noticed that the message will be posted on a Fan Page?

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm encountering the same problem

Comment: Could you provide some of your code?

Comment: Almost one year later, but here's the source code. Not sure if the latest changes on the API will prevent it from working. http://convoymobile.com/devservers/facebook-code/sourcecode.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this is a known issue, see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/379697955378489, you should subscribe to the bug to track its progress.

Comment: I reported the bug con Facebook Developers and posted this question here the next day hoping to have an answer from the community. Unfortunately, Facebook gave a final answer to the bug but seems not to make sense at all. I'll come back as soon as I find out if the latest changes on the API fixed the issue.

Comment: The answer to this question is in the Facebook bug I've submitted and that @DMCS found. Link to the bug report [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407033842673075?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5239a8b0777433f90486303). By default, it is not possible to post with attachments when the user hasn't liked the page but it is possible to post a message.

Answer (score 1):

I don;t know for iOS, but at least for web, you can use the graph api to post to a fan page, and that does not require for the user to have liked the page. Posting to a page via the graph api is still available after the fb changes on February 7th (I've just tried)

Comment: I woudn't coinsider this a good solutions since it requires asking the user for extra permissions which usually raises the user visit bounce rate.

Comment: I don't think Facebook allows anymore for an application to post on behalf of its user without first asking for its permission.

Comment: Indeed @Alina, this post is completely out of date and, therfore, irrelevant. The FB API has changed since.