# iOS Facebook SDK - Share to another page's wall

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to post a message on a Facebook Page (not a user).

On the parameters dictionary, I am adding the "to" key with the target page ID and I am always getting an error message. If I replace the page ID by a user ID, the code works nicely.

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"My Name", @"name",
 @"My caption.", @"caption",
 @"My Description.", @"description",
 @"http://www.mylink.com.br", @"link",
 @"http://www.mylink.com.br/logo.png", @"picture",
 pageID, @"to",
 nil];
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {

}];
```

And here is the error message:

```
An invalid target was specified: 219909461711. The target must be a page, event or user that the actor can post on the wall of.
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance! (:

Comment: have a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196168/how-can-i-use-the-feed-dialog-to-post-on-a-facebook-fan-page-wall-not-liked-by-t