# Can I use the feed dialog (or graph api) to post to a page or person I haven't liked (or am not friends with)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Previously, you were able to post to a person or page that you hadn't liked (or were friends with) via *either* the dialog or graph API. Then there seemed to have been (or always was) [bugs with the feed dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196168/how-can-i-use-the-feed-dialog-to-post-on-a-facebook-fan-page-wall-not-liked-by-t) meaning it could only be done with the graph API.

Now it seems that there have been two updates that have depreciated the ability to use the graph API to post on a persons/page wall

**[February 6th 2013](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)**

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>
> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.

and more recently **[October 6th](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013)**

> **Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API**
>
> We have found that posting content via API (stream.publish) on a friend's wall lead to a high incidence of user dissatisfaction (hiding content, blocking the app). After the migration period, posting content to friends' timelines via stream.publish will no longer be allowed. Please use the Feed Dialog for posting.

- [related blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/)

Both these suggest using the Feed Dialog as an alternative to the new limitations, but I can't seem to get feed dialog to work with posting to anything except liked pages or current friends pages. I'm not sure is this the existing bug or due to the depreciated features. Furthermore, the documentation doesn't mention any of the limitations of the dialogs so it's completely unclear.

Can anyone tell me a way to go about this, or at least clarify the above as being the current situation?

Comment: You're I'm getting the same results. May be its not possible to post to non-friends/non-liked pages' wall - But why have they not mentioned this anywhere in their documentation!

Comment: Has there been any update to this? I'm having the same issue. I can only post to already liked pages and an error is presented when trying to post to a non-liked page.