# FB feed dialog post to page that is not liked by user

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

This is related to the following question, but I think something has changed since that issue was resolved: [How can I use the Feed Dialog to post on a Facebook Fan Page wall not liked by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196168/how-can-i-use-the-feed-dialog-to-post-on-a-facebook-fan-page-wall-not-liked-by-t)

I am getting the same error message:

> An invalid target was specified: 92586461482. The target must be a page, event, or user that the actor can post on the wall of.

The answer that was provided by DMCS was a link to a bug on FB: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407033842673075 where a FB developer said "You can write wall posts to pages, but not post content with attachments. By default, feed dialog publishes content with an attachment. So this is by design and not a bug."

However, as you can see below, I do not have any attachment specified in the parameters and I am still not able to use this code to post to a page that is not liked. I've seen other folks having this same issue as well.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    to: '92586461482'
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Is there a way to pass another parameter that will remove the supposed "default" attachment so this will work for users who do not like the page?